# bash sed replace a line number in a file containing a colon

Tags: bash, sed

I am on RHEL 7.3. Line 12 of `myfile.txt` looks like:

image: `/currentimage/myimage`

I need a bash script to change it to:

image: `/newimage/otherimage`

I tried doing it this way:

```
sed -i '12s/image: /currentimage/myimage/image: /newimage/otherimage/' ./myfile
```

But it fails with:

```
sed: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command "The `/` characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given `s` command. The `/` character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the *regexp* or *replacement* only if it is preceded by a \ character."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `/` as your `sed` separator, AND it is used in your paths. Try using `|` as your separator instead.

```
sed -i '12s|image: /currentimage/myimage|image: /newimage/otherimage|' ./myfile
```

Additionally you can escape each `/` in the file path like so `\/` .

Comment: You could mention it's possible to escape the separator character when you don't want it to behave as such, even it it would be to much of a bother in this case.

Comment: @Kip K Thank you, this works fine. I didn't know you could do that. I guess was focusing on the colon as the source of my problem instead of the escape characters. The pipe solution is very easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `Awk`, it is pretty simple to move on the 12th line using the `NR` variable which represents the line being processed,

```
awk 'NR==12{$2="/newimage/otherimage/"}1' myfile > tmp && mv tmp myfile
```

The part `> tmp && mv tmp myfile` is equivalent to to the `-i` option in `sed` for an indirect way to do modify the file in-place.